# Laravel feature test response original attribute

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

Am doing the below in Laravel 8 feature test. Have below queries. In the browser the route `test.dashboard` returns html response and not a json response

1. `$response` contains a `Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse` instance.   What does original attribute means `$response->original`?

```php
    $response = $this->get(route('test.dashboard'));
    $tests = $response->original['tests'];
```

2. What does the method `assertViewHas` mean? Does it check whether the response has text “tests” in it?

```php
    $response = $this->get(route('test.dashboard'));
    $response->assertViewHas('tests');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. What does original attribute means $response->original ?**

The `original` attribute is an instance of `Illuminate\View\View` object. It represents the original content of the response object.

By doing `$response->original['tests']` you are accessing the 'tests' value in your view's data.
*(`$response->original` is not really a `TestResponse` attribute but a nested attribute in `$response->baseResponse`)*

**2. What does the method `assertViewHas` mean? Does it check whether the response has text “tests” in it ?**

The method [assertViewHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-view-has) checks whether the view has "tests" in its data. To assert text in view you can lookup [assertSee](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-see).

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response .  thanks for the info

Comment: Glad it helped !